# Increment number in href

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I'm a newbie in PHP and struggling with this for a while so any helpers would be appreciated.

Using bootstrap I have an unordered list I'd like to use for displaying records from mysql.

I can display the records no problem in a couple different ways but it seems I can't get this to work with the bootstrap layout I chose. The main issue is trying to append an incrementing number to the following:

```
<?php 

            include 'dbconnect.php';

            $info =  mysql_query("SELECT firstname, lastname, postalcode, date, phone, timeframe, city, available FROM (SELECT * FROM `custdata` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0 , 3) t ORDER BY id ASC") or die(mysql_error());

            $count=1;

            while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($newusers)) {

            echo"
                <div class='panel panel-default'>
                <div class='panel-heading'>
                <h4 class='panel-title'>
                <a data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#accordion_leads' href='#collapse".$count."'>";

                echo $info['firstname']." ".$info['lastname']."<div style= float:right>". $info['postalcode'].""</div>";

                </a></h4></div>";

                echo '<div id="collapse'.$count.'" class="panel-collapse collapse">';

                 echo "<div class="panel-body">";

                      echo 
                      "<ul class=list-group style=font-size:13px>
                      <li class=list-group-item> <strong>Location:</strong>", $info['city'],
                      "</li><li class=list-group-item><strong>Date:</strong>", $info['date'], 
                      "</li><li class=list-group-item><strong>Phone:</strong>", $info['phone'], 
                      "</li><li class=list-group-item> <strong>Timeframe:</strong>", $info['timeframe'], 
                      "</li><li class=list-group-item> <strong>Availability:</strong>", $info['available'],"</li>
                      </ul></div></div>"; 

                     $count ++; } ?>
```

Comment: You can't use php variables like that in html. Use `#collapse{<?php echo $count; ?>}` instead.

Comment: 2nd last line has wrong PHP syntax. Since you are still within PHP scope you need to echo that div and not as it is.

Comment: You should look at @Mohit Jain's answer. It has simple solution to your question.

Comment: The posted HTML and PHP is broken. Fix the syntax errors and come back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this just copy my code and replace yours and you are done

```
<?php 

        $count=1;

        while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($newusers)) {

        echo"
          <div class='panel panel-default'>
            <div class='panel-heading'>
              <h4 class='panel-title'>
                <a data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#accordion_leads' href='#collapse".$count."'>";

                echo $info['firstname']." ".$info['lastname']."<div style= float:right>". $info['postalcode'].""</div>";

                </a></h4></div>";

            echo '<div id="collapse'.$count.'" class="panel-collapse collapse">';

$count ++;
}
?>
```

Comment: I updated all my php code. Not sure where the issue is. Appreciate your feedback

Comment: @user3863088 Try inspecting the code and see whether the dynamic count is there or not

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
<?php
     $count=0;
     while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($newusers)) 
     { ?>
       <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                 <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion_leads" href="#collapse<?php echo $count; ?>">
                   <?php echo  $info['firstname'].", ".$info['lastname']; ?>
                    <div style='float:right'><?php echo ", ".$info['postalcode'] ?></div>
                 </a>
              </h4>
          </div>
       <div id="collapse<?php echo $count; ?>" class="panel-collapse collapse">
     <?php $count ++; } ?>
```

Comment: Already you are in php and then again you are starting php tags but you should concate the string instead of starting php again

Comment: @Veerendra its just becoz its newby with PHP i don't want to make complicated answer for that guy.. :)